# ElasticSearch query for items not in given array

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I am trying to write a part of a query to filter out any items with a type as "group" and that have a group id that isn't in a given array of ids. I started writing a bool query with a must and must_not but I was getting tripped up on how to write "id not in the given array.

EDIT:
 I am actually converting an outdated query using "and" and "not" to be ES 5.5 compatible. Here is the old query that worked.

```
:and => [
  {
    term: {
      type: 'group'
    }
  },
  {
    :not => {
      terms: {
        group_id: group_ids
      }
    }
  },
  {
    :not => {
      terms: {
        user_id: user_ids
      }
    }
  }
]
```

group_ids and user_ids are arrays.

Comment: Use `should` and `minimum_should_match`with the ids you have instead of must and must_not. Other than that, provice some code to elaborate on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool: {
  must: {
    term: {
      kind: 'group'
    }
  },
  must_not: [
    {
      terms: {
        group_id: group_ids
      }
    },
    {
      terms: {
        user_id: user_ids
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not analyzed the arrays with the IDs. You can use a `Bool` query with a `filter` clause, and then within that filter start a new `bool` query with a `mustNot` clause and within that clause add a `terms` query with your IDs.